# PrimeNg AutoComplete Add Non Selectable Value

Tags: angular, primeng

In the dropdown of my autoComplete,
I would like to add at the end of my options a "Adanced search" value that is clickable but not selectable (will not modify the formControlName) and which will trigger a method.

This is what I actually have :

```
<p-autoComplete #autoComplete
    formControlName="application"
    [suggestions]="filteredApplications"
    (completeMethod)="filterApplications()"
    [dropdown]="true"
    (onFocus)="!autoComplete.value && autoComplete.handleDropdownClick($event)">
    <ng-template let-app pTemplate="item">
        <div *ngIf="app!=='Advanced Search'">
            {{app}}
        </div>
        <div *ngIf="app==='Advanced Search'" (click)="searchApp()">
            {{ 'application.advancedSearch' | translate }}
        </div>
    </ng-template>
</p-autoComplete>
```

with filterApplications() :

```
filterApplications(): void {
    let filtered: Array<String> = [];
    let query = this.applicationForm.controls['application'].value;

    for (let i = 0; i < this.applications.length; i++) {
        let application = this.applications[i];
        if (application.toLowerCase().includes(query.toLowerCase())) {
            filtered.push(application);
        }
    }

    this.filteredApplications = filtered;
    this.filteredApplications.push('Advanced Search');
}
```

with this.applications : `@Input() applications: Array<String>`

Atm, when I click on Advanced Search, my formControlName becomes Advanced Search, and i want to keep what I have in my formControlName and just trigger a searchApps() method.